# Не могу корректно отсортировать дату в массиве JS

Tags: javascript, json, сортировка, дата, firebase

Работаю над блогом, использую сервис Firebase в котором создал Realtime database. К сожалению сортировать объекты я там не смог, по этому пришлось прибегнуть к ручной сортировке при получении данных с базы.
Вначале я создал массив, куда буду помещать посты, которые прийдут по запросу:

```
const publicationsArray = [];
```

Далее я обращаюсь к базе данный чтобы достать посты

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
   //...
});
```

Складываю посты в массив `publicationsArray`

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
   snapshot.forEach((item) => {
     publicationsArray.push(item.val());
   });
});
```

Данные приходят в JSON формате, и каждый пост выглядит так:

```
0: {
  postDate: "02.01.2021, 14:02",
  postDescription: "Подготовьте продукты для капкейков на молоке...",
  postId: "MFxSPILrXs",
  postImage: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/18/15/40/cookies-1835414_960_720.jpg",
  postHeading: "Рецепт вкусных новогодних кексов!",
  postType: "education"
}
```

Далее идёт сортировка объектов в массиве:

```
publicationsArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.postDate > b.postDate) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.postDate < b.postDate) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

А после сортировки вывод на страницу:

```
publicationsArray.forEach(item => {        
    postsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
    <div class="post" data-post-id="${item.postId}" data-post-type="${item.postType}">
    <div class="edit-post">
      <button class="edit-button"><i class="far fa-ellipsis-h"></i></button>
      <ul class="edit-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="edit-content">Редактировать пост</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body">
      <div class="post-image">
        <img src="${item.postImage}" alt="">
      </div>
      <p class="post-heading">${item.postHeading}</p>
      <pre class="post-text">${item.postDescription}</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="post-footer">
      <p class="post-type">${item.postType}</p> 
      <p class="post-date">${item.postDate}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    `);
});
```

Всё сортируется правильно, **НО** вот незадача, начиная с этого года, новые посты уходят в самый низ, я так понял что что-то неладное с датой, и так оно и есть, ведь `"31.12.2020, 23:40" < "02.01.2021, 14:02"` получится `false`

Тут весь код:

```
const publicationsArray = [];
function getPostsFromDataBase() {
  firebase.database().ref('posts/').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((item) => {
      publicationsArray.push(item.val());
    });

    publicationsArray.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a.postDate > b.postDate) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.postDate < b.postDate) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    publicationsArray.forEach(item => {        
        postsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
        <div class="post" data-post-id="${item.postId}" data-post-type="${item.postType}">
        <div class="edit-post">
          <button class="edit-button"><i class="far fa-ellipsis-h"></i></button>
          <ul class="edit-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="edit-content">Редактировать пост</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="post-body">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="${item.postImage}" alt="">
          </div>
          <p class="post-heading">${item.postHeading}</p>
          <pre class="post-text">${item.postDescription}</pre>
        </div>
        <div class="post-footer">
          <p class="post-type">${item.postType}</p> 
          <p class="post-date">${item.postDate}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        `);
    });
  })
```

Как я могу усовершенствовать, улучшить, дработать эту функцию? Нужно чтобы массив сортировал объекты согласно датам правильно. Прошу протянуть руку помощи :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант - привести строку к дате и использовать это в сортировке:

```
publicationsArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(b.postDate) - new Date(a.postDate);
});
```

Comment: Не помогает... для даты начиная с 2021 года всё работает, и строка преобразуется. а вот для остальных пишет Invalid Date

Comment: А какого формата приходят даты до 2021?

Comment: Все данные приходят в виде String ```"день.месяц.год, часы:минуты"```

Comment: Да, в таком формате дата может и не распарситься.
Тогда нужно привести дату к тому формату, который сможет обработать JS - ``YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm``. Метод для форматирования можно реальзовать самостоятельно или воспользоваться какой-то библиотекой, типа Moment.js.


[Более подробно о датах в JS](https://learn.javascript.ru/date)

Comment: Сказали не использовать библиотеки, так что всё сделаю вручную, за подсказку большое спасибо! (я про ```YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ```)

Comment: ```date.toLocaleDateString('ru', {year:"2-digit", day:"2-digit", month: "2-digit", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"}).replaceAll(".", "-");```